# Slack API: Ignore deleted/deactivated users on a conversations.members request

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack, slack-api

I'm trying to develop a little script that fetches all the users from a channel. I managed to do it, but it retrieves much more users than the ones that are currently on the channel (on the app are 102, on the request I get 202). After checking the documentation I see that it gives back also the deleted/deactivated users. I try to filter with if (user.deleted == false) but it happens that all the users (even the ones that are not included in the channel anymore) have deleted as false.

How could I just get the activated users, or at least get info about which users are deleted/deactivated in order to filter them? I'm researching for some time now but I don't find any answer, I would really appreciate some help.

This is the request:

```
const generalChannelRes = await web.conversations.members('C02Q3F80V', { limit: 500 })

try {
  let fixture = await Promise.all(generalChannelRes.members.map(async userId => {
    const user = await web.users.info(userId)

    if (!user.deleted) {
      const userData = [user.user.profile.email, user.user.name]
      return userData
  }}))

  fixture = fixture.filter(u => u)

  fs.writeFileSync('./models/fixture-users-new.json', JSON.stringify(fixture, null, 
  2))
 })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was very silly, the check on the conditional statement I was using was wrong, doing `if (!user.user.deleted)` I can get the activated/not-deleted users :)